# formal andjoints in hermitian structures

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Given a hermitian vectorbundle $E\to \Sigma$ on a complex plane. The hermitian structure be given by $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$. Let $A \in \Omega^1 (\Sigma; End(E))$ be a complex smooth bundle map, given locally by
$$
A = a~d\bar{z} - \bar{a}^T dz.
$$
How does one have to think about $\langle dz, \cdot \rangle$? What is the formal adjoint?

Maybe $\langle dz, \cdot \rangle = \langle  \cdot, d\bar{z} \rangle$ ?

Why does $A$ satisfy $\langle A\sigma,\tau  \rangle = - \langle \sigma,A \tau \rangle$?

Comment: What is $a$ here? I presume it is a section of $\text{End}(E)$?